# Twitter login doesn't work correctly

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, twitter

I have a big problems with login to app I am working on through Twitter (I am testing on localhost).
For the login via Twitter I use gem called **omniauth-twitter**.

I implemented all necessary things around and the authentication "works". "Works" is in quotation marks because from 10 attempts I got:

- 2x I successfully authenticated
- 5x I got the error `(twitter) Authentication failure! timeout: Timeout::Error, execution expired`
- 3x the page shut down

I am desperate from this behavior of authentication, because this is unusable...

Why the authentication falling down so often times? Is there any saver and more reliable way, how to authenticate with Twitter?

**EDIT: Just a little bit from log:**

```
(twitter) Request phase initiated.
(twitter) Callback phase initiated.
```

The first line is in the termina window printed out, when a man click on the link LOGIN VIA TWITTER, the second one when is detected callback address (set up on `http://127.0.0.1:3001`).
If is occurred an error, then:

```
(twitter) Request phase initiated.
(twitter) Callback phase initiated.
(twitter) Authentication failure! timeout: Timeout::Error, execution expired
```

Comment: I've been using omniauth-twitter for a while now, and never had any of these problems... Is there any helpful stuff in the logs?

Comment: hi @Robin, I added to the original post the errors I got.

Answer (score 0):

with out seeing any code I think your best best it to create a whole new app where its only using the omniauth-twitter and see if you can reproduce the problem in a isolated simple app. This will will help rule out that its a different part of your bigger app.